# Scanf continuous input in C

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    double a=0;
    char b=0;
    scanf ("%d%c",&a,&b);
    printf ("%d,%c", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my code for a quick test program I wrote to play around with the scanf function in C. I am trying to have the user input something like 78X + 5 = 19 (then hit enter) and then parse that into variables a, b, and c where in this case a=78, b=5, c=19. In the sample code, when I type in 78X, c doesn't store a value to b and only prints "78, " and then terminates. Why won't it store a value to b?

Comment: This is not the way to do it. "78X+5 = 19" is a string with respect to C so you need to treat the whole expression as a string parse through it and fetch the required values for a,b and c

Comment: You're not going to get far with `scanf` as it is not very flexible for any more than basic input. Look into using a regex library or write a more detailed parser.

Answer (score 0):

The `,` in your format string is significant. The string `%d,%c` would match the input `78,x` but it would not match `78x` .

Also you need to use `%f` to scan and print a `double`.  Using `%d` causes undefined behaviour (which may manifest itself as `b` seeming to not appear).  Either change to `%f`, or change your `double` to an `int`.

Comment: Tried that and recompiled, doesn't fix it.

Comment: changed the scanf to scanf ("%d%c", &a, &b);

Answer (score 0):

If your input is 75x then below is the code which reads the value and stores it in `a(75)` and `b(x)` respectively

```
   #include <stdio.h>
    int main ()
    {
        int a=0;
        char b=0;
        scanf ("%d%c",&a,&b);
        printf ("%d%c", a, b);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this!
A quick followup question: If I initialize int a=0 and use %d as a format specifier it works fine, but if I initialize double a=0 and use %f as a format specifier it outputs 0.0000, X. Why is this?

Comment: Use %lf while scanning